# Using lambda or linq driven query to get a WCF paged result

Tags: vb.net, wcf, linq, lambda

I am fairly new to WCF.  I am attempting to retrieve a query from a WCF service using linq or lambda as a paged response and just not getting it.  My code is as follows:

```
Dim uri As New Uri(My.Settings.Host)
Dim context As New PMXMigrationEntities(uri)
Dim token As DataServiceQueryContinuation(Of APARTMNT) = Nothing
Dim list As New List(Of APARTMNT)

Try
    ' Execute the query for all apartments and get the response object.'
    Dim response As QueryOperationResponse(Of APARTMNT) = _
        CType(context.APARTMNTs.Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of APARTMNT))

    ' With a paged response from the service, use a do...while loop '
    ' to enumerate the results before getting the next link. '
    Do
        ' If nextLink is not null, then there is a new page to load.'
        If token IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Load the new page from the next link URI.'
            response = CType(context.Execute(Of APARTMNT)(token),  _
            QueryOperationResponse(Of APARTMNT))
        End If

        ' Enumerate the apartments in the response.'
        For Each a As APARTMNT In response
            list.Add(a)
        Next

        ' Get the next link, and continue while there is a next link.'
        token = response.GetContinuation()
    Loop While token IsNot Nothing
Catch ex As DataServiceQueryException
    Throw New ApplicationException( _
            "An error occurred during query execution.", ex)
End Try

Return list
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
CType(context.APARTMNTs.Where(Function(a) a.city.Contains(cityStr)).Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of APARTMNT))
```

And something like:

```
CType(context.APARTMNTs.Where(Function(a) a.city = cityStr).Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of APARTMNT))
```

Now, I have read that in this scenario, the linq or lambda is translated into an OData query which doesn't support the Contains function, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData doesn't support the generic Contains operator on collections (although with any/all it's not completely true anymore). But on a string (assuming a.city is a string property) you can use indexof instead. For example:

```
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=indexof(CompanyName, 'Futt') ne -1
```

This query is basically equivalent to CompanyName.Contains("Futt"). In LINQ this would look something like:

```
context.Customers.Where(Function(c) c.CompanyName.IndexOf("Futt") <> -1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  +1 for the attempt but that's not the answer I was looking for though.  I was initially attempting to avoid using an OData URI directly. It took a while and a lot of trial and error but I figured it out.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand, the LINQ example is part of the response. Doesn't matter - glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

After a lengthy amount of researching and dead ends, I figured it out.  It's a matter of casting the DataServiceQuery as a QueryOperatorResponse

```
var query = (DataServiceQuery<TENANT>)context.TENANTs.Where(a => a.name.ToLower().Contains("jeff"));

// Execute the query for all tenants and get the response object.
   QueryOperationResponse<TENANT> response =
               (QueryOperationResponse<TENANT>)query.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<TENANT>;
```